# sum of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\times_k K\rightarrow X$ be the projection for a finite field extension and $X$ lets say a projective (or proper) scheme over $k$. Is it right that one has for a line bundle $L$ on $X\times_k K$: $f^*f_*L\simeq L^{\oplus d}$, where $d$ is the degree of the extension?

Comment: But projection formula is $f_*(\mathcal{F}\otimes f^*\mathcal{E})\simeq f_*\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{E}$ and I am interested in $f^*f_*L$

Comment: sorry, let me delete my comment.

Comment: $f^*(f_*L)=L\otimes_k K=L\otimes_K (K\otimes_k K)$. As $K$-vector spaces, we have $K\otimes_k K\simeq K^d$ where $d=[K:k]$. So $L\otimes_K (K\otimes_k K)\simeq L\otimes_K K^d=L^{\oplus d}$.

Comment: Ok, but why $f^*(f_*L)=L\otimes_k K=L\otimes_K(K\otimes_k K)$ ?

Comment: The first equality is because $f$ is an affine morphism, check the equality on the affine open subschemes of $X$. The second equality is a standard property of tensor product.